# French caracter from csv in c#

Tags: c#, csv, character-encoding

I create a C# soft which take as parameter a CSV which contain a list of folder like :

[image]

I read the file whis this code :

```
public projectTree(string _path) 
    { 
        path = _path; 
        try 
        { 
            confFile = File.ReadAllText(path); 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fichier", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
        } 
        lines = confFile.Split('\n'); 
        foreach (string line in lines) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                FolderInfo tmp = new FolderInfo(); 
                if (line.IndexOf(';') >= 0) 
                { 
                    if (line.Split(';')[1].Count() > 0) 
                        tmp.name = line.Split(';')[1]; 
                    else 
                        tmp.valid = false; 
                    if (line.Split(';')[2].Count() > 0) 
                        tmp.RACL_ReadOnly = line.Split(';')[2]; 
                    else 
                        tmp.valid = false; 
                    if (line.Split(';')[3].Count() > 0) 
                        tmp.RACL_Users = line.Split(';')[3]; 
                    else 
                        tmp.valid = false; 
                    if (line.Split(';')[4].Count() > 0) 
                        tmp.RACL_Managers = line.Split(';')[4]; 
                    else 
                        tmp.valid = false; 
                    if (line.Split(';')[5].Count() > 0) 
                        tmp.RACL_Partners = line.Split(';')[5]; 
                    else 
                        tmp.valid = false; 
                    if (tmp.valid == true) 
                    { 
                        ACLs.Add(tmp); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
            catch 
            { 
                return; 
            } 
        } 
    }
```

The soft create folders from this list but when creating the "02-Ôlololéééèèç" folder, the folder is created as :

[image]

How can I handle this characters ?

Comment: What is the encoding of the CSV? Windows 1252 or UTF-8 or UTF-16? How do you read the CSV? Code please. See also how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Should be using a RichTextBox instead of a Textbox.

Comment: I'am not using textbox for the folder name.

Comment: Which encoding you have iso-8859-1 or UTF-8?

Comment: How can I know which one i'am using ?

Comment: The `ReadAllText` method has an overload where you can specify the encoding of the input file. I assume you used Excel to create the CSV? Try `File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))`

Comment: It works ! Thank you !

Comment: Your code uses the encoding that you make it use (see the documentation for defaults if you aren't making it explicit). Your code should be the using the encoding that the file is written with. Only the writer can tell you what that is. There are hundreds. Programs such as Notepad++ can be given a sample, rule out encodings that the sample is not valid for and guess from those remaining. The guess may or may not fully work with the current sample file contents and may be invalid for future file contents. Without knowing the encoding, you have data loss and a failed communication.

Comment: Obligatory link: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading files make sure to specify the encoding - especially when reading non-UTF-8 encoded files. If you are unsure of a file's encoding, you can open it in [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or any other text editor capable of handling various encodings, and simply look it up:

[image: See file encoding in Notepad++]

Default ANSI encoding for Wester European languages is Windows 1252, so you need to change your reading line to:

```
confFile = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```